# sorting is not working in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am struggling with sorting query!! When I will execute same query with mongo shell

```
db.locations.find({"$and":[{"timestamp":{"$gte":1438328404766,"$lte":1438329404766}}]}).sort({"timestamp":1})
```

getting sorted result.
But doing it by code then getting unordered result. Can you look following code and let me know if anything is going wrong with this code.

```
//part of function(condition, offset, limit, sortByColumn, ordering, fields)

        logger.debug('Filter condition is '+JSON.stringify(condition));

        var instance ;

        if (fields) {
            instance = self.model.find(condition, fields);
        } else {
            instance = self.model.find(condition);
        }

        // start record from
        if (!_.isEmpty(offset)) {
            logger.debug('Offset is : '+ offset);
            instance.skip(offset);
        }

        if (sortByColumn ) {
            //default ordering is asc
            ordering = !(ordering) ? 1 : ordering;          
            instance.sort({sortByColumn: ordering});

            logger.debug('sorting with sortByColumn : '+sortByColumn+' Ordering : '+ ordering);
        }

        if (!_.isEmpty(limit)) {
            logger.debug('Limit is : '+ limit);

            instance.limit(limit);
        }

        instance.execAsync()
                .then(function(results) {

                    logger.debug('result is : ' + JSON.stringify(results));

                    return resolve(results);
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    return reject(error);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you assign a variable to the key of an object like this:

```
    if (sortByColumn ) {
        //default ordering is asc
        ordering = !(ordering) ? 1 : ordering; 

        // declare an object
        var sorting = {};

        // Assign like this
        sorting[sortByColumn] = ordering;

        instance.sort(sorting);     // Use the object

        logger.debug('sorting with sortByColumn : '+sortByColumn+' Ordering : '+ ordering);
    }
```

So you use the "bracket" notation to assign a variable, otherwise it is just treated as a "literal" key name, thus:

```
var sortByColumn = "theColumnIAskedFor";
{ "sortByColumn": 1 }          // Not what I want :(
```

Mine comes out as:

```
var sortByColumn = "theColumnIAskedFor";
{ "theColumnIAskedFor": 1 }    // Yey! :->
```

Comment: Yeap! Its a silly mistake! I wanna kill myself! :D Thanks

Comment: @ManishTrivedi Don't forget the accept. You can vote too for the nice explanation.

Comment: stack-overflow told me that you can accept it after 2 min so I did late for vote.  :) :)

Comment: @ManishTrivedi Yes it does that. I't supposed to stop coworkers from posting question/answer combinations just to improve their rep score.